# How do you display an image on a panel in Java? [Beginner]

Tags: java, image, panel, frame

I need to put a menu in a game, so I've created a frame called menuFrame and a panel called menuPanel. I've been able to get a button and a label with text to appear on this panel, but I can't get an image to display.

Here is the bulk of my code:

```
try {
JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("background2.png"));
JLabel menuLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
    menuLabel.setSize(800, 540);
    menuLabel.setLocation(0, 0);
    menuLabel.setVisible(true);         
    menuPanel.add(menuLabel);
    this.add(menuPanel);
    menuPanel.grabFocus();
    menuPanel.requestFocusInWindow();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I've been messing with it for a very long time, and the image simply wont appear. I've tried using just ImageIcon and no BufferedImage and that didn't work. I put the image in the same package as the class.

Comment: I think that [Beginner] tag is successful at distracting the moderators

Comment: @gpasch this tag can be useful to tell people answering that the problem might not be something very complcated, but rather something simple that the OP might not know about/overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon("background2.png");
JLabel menuLabel = new JLabel();
label.setBounds(0, 0, x, y);
label.setIcon(imgIcon);
```

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I'm getting no image. Here is my code now:   http://prntscr.com/bei217

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("background2.png"));
JLabel menuLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
    menuLabel.setSize(800, 540);
    menuLabel.setLocation(0, 0);
    menuLabel.setVisible(true);         
    menuPanel.add(menuLabel);
    this.add(menuPanel); //This might not work, try the name of the JFrame instance
    menuPanel.grabFocus();
    menuPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
    this.revalidate() //Use the name of the JFrame if this is not a JFrame or if this.add(menuPanel); doesnt work
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Re-validation is very important